# How to check a checkbox in mechanize for python and run the event associated to the checkbox?

Tags: python, mechanize-python

The problem is that the form has a checkbox that has an event:

```
<input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;CheckBox1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" />
```

When I tried to checked, the checkbox do got checked:

`CheckboxControl(CheckBox1=[*on])>`

But the event doesn't run.

I tried by using `br.submit()`, but what happen is that the checkbox got unchecked:

`CheckboxControl(CheckBox1=[on])>`

Answer (score 1):

Mechanize doesn't include a javascript interpreter at all.  You need a "headless browser".